# IText7 pdfHtml not working in Azure Web App

Tags: itext7, pdfhtml

I currently have my export to pdf working perfectly in my local, but after I publish to Azure web app, it does not work.  Any suggestions?  Does this work in Azure? Is it the chromeless thing that will only work on Linux? Confused...

Using .NET6 MVC

EDIT:

```
    [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Export(string Form, string sessionId, string fullname)
            {
                FontProvider provider = new DefaultFontProvider();
                string saveDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHmmss");
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
                    properties.SetFontProvider(new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true));
                    MediaDeviceDescription mediaDeviceDescription = new MediaDeviceDescription(iText.StyledXmlParser.Css.Media.MediaType.PRINT);
                    properties.SetMediaDeviceDescription(mediaDeviceDescription);
                    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(Form, stream, properties);
                    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", fullname + "_" + saveDate +".pdf");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please post the details of what you have tried, description of errors etc

Comment: just a quick comment that pdfHTML does not use any browser engine to do its bidding

Comment: That's just it. There is literally not an error.  I test locally, works like a charm, deploy click exact same button that works locally and it does not work. I added the code I call into EDIT of post.

Comment: Have you tried to replace pdfHTML part with some dummy memory stream byte writing functionality? That would help you understand whether the difference in behavior comes from the I/O or other "infrastructural" code part, or it's coming from pdfHTML

Answer (score 0):

I was using itext 7 everything works fine in Console application. When I use same code in Web/Function App project, I started getting below error.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=itext.html2pdf
  StackTrace:
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Tags.BrTagWorker..ctor(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultTagWorkerMapping.<>c.<.cctor>b__1_10(IElementNode lhs, ProcessorContext rhs)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.ProcessDocument(INode root, PdfDocument pdfDocument)
   at iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(String html, PdfDocument pdfDocument, ConverterProperties converterProperties)
   at iTextSample.ConsoleApp.HtmlToPdfBuilder.RenderPdf() in C:\code\iTextSample.ConsoleApp\HtmlToPdfBuilder.cs:line 227
```

After some investigation found that the `<br />` tag was a problem. I removed all `<br />` tags and it is working fine.